# Separator in the output after regex filter on a list

Tags: python, regex, list

I am new to python so bear with me, please.

I have a list-

```
print(listoffiles)
["{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n"]
```

I need only the filename from this list,

```
0_HONOR_1524204351030, 0_HONOR_1524204351030,0_HONOR_1524204351030
```

I first split it this way -

```
listoffiles=[i.split(":")[0] for i in listoffiles]
print(listoffiles)
["{'0_HONOR_1524204351030'", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030'", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030'"]
```

and then join it-

```
listoffiles=(','.join(str(f) for f in listoffiles))
print(listoffiles)
{'0_HONOR_1524204351030',{'0_HONOR_1524204351030',{'0_HONOR_1524204351030'
```

Here on, I tried to strip it-

```
listoffiles=(str(listoffiles).strip("'{'"))
print(listoffiles)
0_HONOR_1524204351030',{'0_HONOR_1524204351030',{'0_HONOR_1524204351030'
```

This seemed to only work for the first element, so I tried this as well-

```
listoffiles=(str(f).strip("'{'") for f in listoffiles)
print(listoffiles)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fda38837460>
```

Since that didn't work as well, I gave it a try with regular expressions-

```
regex = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$')
newlistoffiles=filter(regex.match,listoffiles)
```

This one seemed to work but I am unable to separate the output-

```
0_HONOR_15242043510300_HONOR_15242043510300_HONOR_1524204351030
```

I need help separating these.
I posted the entire problem so that I can get suggestions on any other better and smart ways to get this task done as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **ast module** to convert your string dict to python dict and use `keys()` to the required key.

**Ex:**

```
import ast
listoffiles = ["{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n"]
listoffiles = map(ast.literal_eval, listoffiles)
print([i.keys()[0] for i in listoffiles])
```

**Output:**

```
['0_HONOR_1524204351030', '0_HONOR_1524204351030', '0_HONOR_1524204351030', '0_HONOR_1524204351030', '0_HONOR_1524204351030']
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't even know about the module. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split to seperate the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

Data = ["{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n", "{'0_HONOR_1524204351030': 'NEW'}\n"]

for i in Data:
    i = i.strip()
    i = i[2:]
    i = i[0:i.index("'")]
    print(i)
```

Will print:

```
0_HONOR_1524204351030
0_HONOR_1524204351030
0_HONOR_1524204351030
0_HONOR_1524204351030
0_HONOR_1524204351030
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it splitting it over several lists:

```
all_strs = [j for i, j in enumerate(lst)]

#assumes that this string format will remain constant
lsts = [list(all_strs[i])[2:23] for i, j in enumerate(all_strs)]

keys = [''.join(j) for i, j in enumerate(lsts)]
print(keys)

['0_HONOR_1524204351030',
'0_HONOR_1524204351030',
'0_HONOR_1524204351030',
'0_HONOR_1524204351030',
'0_HONOR_1524204351030']
```